# Replacing pattern after nth match is found on each line?

Tags: shell, shell-script, sed, awk

I have a file containing lines:

```
india;austria;japan;chile
china;US;nigeria;mexico;russia
```

I want to replace all the occurences of semicolon on each line with e.g. `;NEW;`, but starting from the 2nd occurence only. The result should look like this:

```
india;austria;NEW;japan;NEW;chile
china;US;NEW;nigeria;NEW;mexico;NEW;russia
```

I tried this with gsub, but it replaces all the occurences:
 `awk '/;/{gsub(/;/,";NEW;") }{print}'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `awk` solution is much longer, but is easier to make it generic:

```
awk -F\; '{for(i=1;i<NF;i++)printf"%s;%s",$i,(i>=2)?"NEW;":"";print$NF}' replacefile
```

Is possible to do it with `sed` too, making a loop with the `t` command and always replacing the 2nd (or whichever you want) separator into some temporary mark (usually `\n`):

```
sed ':b;s/;/\n/2;tb;s/\n/;NEW;/g' replacefile
```

Answer (score 7):

There's a flag for GNU sed's `s///` command that does this:

```
sed 's/;/;NEW;/2g' <<END
india;austria;japan;chile
china;US;nigeria;mexico;russia
END
```

outputs

```
india;austria;NEW;japan;NEW;chile
china;US;NEW;nigeria;NEW;mexico;NEW;russia
```

See https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command

> The `s` command can be followed by zero or more of the following flags:
>
> `g`
>
> > Apply the replacement to all matches to the regexp, not just the first.
>
> *number*
>
> > Only replace the *number*th match of the regexp.
> >     Note: the posix standard does not specify what should happen when you mix the `g` and *number* modifiers, and currently there is no widely agreed upon meaning across sed implementations. **For GNU sed, the interaction is defined to be: ignore matches before the *number*th, and then match and replace all matches from the *number*th on.**
>
> ...

(emphasis mine)

Comment: Great! I never noticed you can combine `g` and number flags.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do this in two steps:

First, replace all semicolons with `;NEW;`:

```
sed -e s/\;/\;NEW\;/g
```

Then replace the first `;NEW;` with a semicolon:

```
sed -e s/\;NEW\;/\;/
```

You can use a pipe to do both replaces on one line. Here's an example:

```
$ more replacefile 
india;austria;japan;chile;
china;US;nigeria;mexico;russia
$ cat replacefile |sed -e s/\;/\;NEW\;/g  |sed -e s/\;NEW\;/\;/
india;austria;NEW;japan;NEW;chile;NEW;
china;US;NEW;nigeria;NEW;mexico;NEW;russia
```

Comment: thanks, but i was hoping that i could get something generalized for an nth match(1,2,3,4 or 5)

Answer (score 1):

I can do it with more code but no loops!

*Data*

```
china;US;nigeria;mexico;russia
iindia;austria;japan;chile
```

*Script*

```awk
BEGIN{ FS=";" }{
    insert=$param
    ix=index($0, insert) + length(insert)

    if (NF <= $param) {
            rest = substr($0,ix,length($0))
            gsub(";",";NEW;",rest)
            line = substr($0,0,ix) rest

            gsub(";;",";",line)
            gsub(";$","",line)
            print line

} else {print}}
```

*Example*

```
 Microknoppix v # awk -f replaceNth.awk -v param=2 countries
 china;US;NEW;nigeria;NEW;mexico;NEW;russia
 iindia;austria;NEW;japan;NEW;chile
```

Comment: Oops, sorry for the failed correction. But something is still not completely correct. There should be “NEW” marks after all fields starting with the _param_ th one.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood the problem :\

Comment: I think this deserves an upvote because it's obviously easier to memorize, maintain and explain. In fact, this is the new "Hello world"

Comment: Much better, but will still fail string like “china;[dominican republic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominican_Republic);nigeria; [dominica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominica);russia” and param=4. (The space in the string is just to satisfy the Markdown parser's caprice.)